# How do I create LinkedIn login in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, authentication, linkedin-api, flutter-packages

I'm trying to create a login with LinkedIn for flutter web and I've tried to use both packages

[flutter_linkedin](https://pypi.org/project/linkedin-scraper/)

and

[linkedin_login](https://pub.dev/packages/linkedin_login)

but it appears to work only on mobile versions, help would be appreciated.